# Create a view from Lotus Notes mail search

Tags: lotus-notes

I can create a search in Lotus Notes Mail like this:

(![From] CONTAINS (/DOLPHINGEO))

and I get all the mails that are not internal.

Can I make this into a View?

Thanks
Liam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, create a view with following selection formula:

```
SELECT Form = "Memo" & !@Contains(From; "/DOLPHINGEO")
```

You might need to add other conditions in additions depending on what you want to see in your view.

Comment: Thanks! worked great. Just needed a small tweak: SELECT Form = "Memo" & (!@Contains(From; "DOLPHINGEO"))

Answer (score 0):

This is still not quite correct. You're likely to have mail that should appear in the view, but which is not on the Memo form (it might be on a Reply or calendar entry form, for instance). Also, chances are you have some mail from people in your company, that was delivered by internet rather than Notes mail, and might not contain the exact string "DOLPHINGEO", uppercase.